# Javascript date is invalid on iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I'm working on a Phonegap-based iOS app, which is already done for Android. The following lines are working fine for Android but not for iOS. Why?

```
var d = new Date("2015-12-31 00:00:00");
console.log(d.getDate() + '. ' + d.getMonth() + ' ' + d.getFullYear();
```

Result for Android:

```
31.11 2015
```

Result on iOS:

```
NaN. NaN NaN
```

Where is the difference coming from?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Your date string is not in a format specified to work with `new Date`. The only formats in the spec are [a simplified version of ISO-8601](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format) (added in ES5 in 2009 and updated in ES2015 and ES2016), and the format output by [`Date.prototype.toString`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring). Your string isn't in either format, but it's really close to the ISO-8601-like format. It would also be easy to change it to a format that isn't in the spec, but is universally supported

Four options for you:

- Use the upcoming `Temporal` feature (it's now at Stage 3)
- The specified format
- An unspecified format that's near-universally supported
- Parse it yourself

#### Use the upcoming `Temporal` feature

The [`Temporal` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) is at Stage 3 as of this update in August 2021. You can use it to parse your string, either treating it as UTC or as local time:

Treating the string as UTC:

```js
// (Getting the polyfill)
const {Temporal} = temporal;

const dateString = "2015-12-31 00:00:00";
const instant = Temporal.Instant.from(dateString.replace(" ", "T") + "Z");
// Either use the Temporal.Instant directly:
console.log(instant.toLocaleString());
// ...or get a Date object:
const dt = new Date(instant.epochMilliseconds);
console.log(dt.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@js-temporal/polyfill/dist/index.umd.js"></script>
```

Or treating it as local time:

```js
// (Getting the polyfill)
const {Temporal} = temporal;

const dateString = "2015-12-31 00:00:00";

console.log("Parsing as local time:");
const tz = Temporal.Now.timeZone();
const instant = tz.getInstantFor(dateString.replace(" ", "T"));
console.log(instant.toLocaleString());
const dt = new Date(instant.epochMilliseconds);
console.log(dt.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@js-temporal/polyfill/dist/index.umd.js"></script>
```

`Temporal` doesn't have the problem mentioned below that the specified date/time string format historically had when no timezone was specified.

#### The ISO-8601-like format

If you change the space to a `T`, you'll be in spec:

```js
var dateString = "2015-12-31 00:00:00";
// Treats the string as local time -- BUT READ BELOW, this varied
var d = new Date(dateString.replace(" ", "T"));
console.log(d.toString());
```

(I'm assuming you're not actually using a string literal, hence the `replace` call.)

For reliable timezone handling in old browsers, you'll also want to append a `Z` (for GMT/UTC) or a timezone indicator (`+`/`-` `HH:MM`), because the handling of strings without them was mis-specified in ES5, updated in ES2015, and then updated further in ES2016. Current versions of modern browsers follow the spec now, which says:

- If there's a time on the string but and no timezone indicator, parse the string in local time
- If there's no time on the string and no timezone indicator, parse the string in UTC

([ES5 said](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-date-time-string-format) always default to UTC. [ES2015 said](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) always default to local time. [ES2016](https://262.ecma-international.org/7.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) is where the current behavior was defined. It's been stable since.)

So it's best to include a timezone indicator, especially if you have to support older browsers. Note that it must be a `Z` (UTC) or `+`/`-` `HH:MM`; abbreviations like `CST` are not allowed, as there's no standard for them. Here's a UTC example:

```js
var dateString = "2015-12-31 00:00:00";
// Treat the string as UTC
var d = new Date(dateString.replace(" ", "T") + "Z");
console.log(d.toString());
```

#### An unspecified format that's near-universally supported

There's a seconnd format that isn't in the specification but is near-universally supported and has been for a long time: `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`, which is interpreted as local time. So:

```js
var dateString = "2015-12-31 00:00:00";
// Treats the string as local time
var d = new Date(dateString.replace(/-/g, "/"));
console.log(d.toString());
```

Again, though, that's unspecified behavior, so caveat emptor. But it works in at least IE8+ (probably earlier), Chrome and anything else using the V8 JavaScript engine, Firefox, and Safari.

#### Parse it yourself

It's also easy to parse that string yourself. Using ES2020+ features:

```js
function parseDate(str) {
    const [dateparts, timeparts] = str.split(" ");
    const [year, month, day] = dateparts.split("-");
    const [hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0] = timeparts?.split(":") ?? [];
    // Treats the string as UTC, but you can remove the `Date.UTC` part and use
    // `new Date` directly to treat the string as local time
    return new Date(Date.UTC(+year, +month - 1, +day, +hours, +minutes, +seconds));
}

const dateString = "2015-12-31 00:00:00";
const d = parseDate(dateString);
console.log(d.toString());
```

Or with only ES5-level features (since the question is from 2015):

```js
function parseDate(str) {
    var parts = str.split(" ");
    var dateparts = parts[0].split("-");
    var timeparts = (parts[1] || "").split(":");
    var year = +dateparts[0];
    var month = +dateparts[1];
    var day = +dateparts[2];
    var hours = timeparts[0] ? +timeparts[0] : 0;
    var minutes = timeparts[1] ? +timeparts[1] : 0;
    var seconds = timeparts[2] ? +timeparts[2] : 0;
    // Treats the string as UTC, but you can remove the `Date.UTC` part and use
    // `new Date` directly to treat the string as local time
    return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes, seconds));
}

var dateString = "2015-12-31 00:00:00";
var d = parseDate(dateString);
console.log(d.toString());
```

Comment: @NULL: I've never seen a JavaScript engine that didn't support it. IE6 and up do, every version of Firefox I've ever seen, every version of Chrome, every version of Opera. **But**, one must always test on ones target environments (whether something is "standard" or not, sadly).

Comment: In my own testing I found that the `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS` solution gives the same date on iOS as I was hoping to get from `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, whereas the solution replacing the space with a `T` adjusted my date by the timezone amount .. (adding on 10 hours to the time).  (Summary:  **`YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`  works**,  `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` gets adjusted for timezone and for some situations that will be wrong)

Comment: @user1290746: Probably the `Z` error in the specification, I've added a note about it above.

Comment: @user1290746 thats because adding T converts it to universal time format. the other solution is better replacing '-' with '/'

Comment: @rorypicko—UTC is a standard, not a format. The T is required for standards compliance, the missing timezone means it will be treated as "local" per the host timezone offset. Omitting the T means it's treated as invalid in Safari. Replacing '-' with '/' means browsers fall back to their own heuristics, it might be treated as local or an invalid date string.

Comment: I went with the `/` solution. Worked perfectly fine. Thanks!. Had the problem on both Chrome and Safari for iOS.

Comment: var dateString = "2015-12-31 00:00:00";
var d = new Date(dateString.replace(/-/g, '/'));

This is working correctly.

Comment: @AjayPatidar - Only because of non-standard parsing, and you can't be sure what timezone it'll use, cross-browser. Use the standard format. It's standadrized. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - It's 2020, and the solution still applicable with my project :). Had to deal with date stored in "2015-05-30 00:00:00" format, and JavaScript in iOs (I am assuming its running off Safari) still churned out the NaN. Great solution!

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell you why. Maybe because iOS doesn't support the Javascript Date function as well as Android, or support a different format?

But I can give you a workaround:

```
var s = "2015-12-31 00:00:00".split(" ")[0].split("-"),
    d = new Date( s[0], s[1], s[2], 0, 0, 0 );

console.log(d);
```

---

```
var s = "2015-12-31 00:00:00".replace(/[ :]/g, "-").split("-"),
    d = new Date( s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5] );

console.log(d);
```

Comment: I will try it and get back to you

Comment: This is a valid solution. Works on both iOS and the rest.
However, for some reason if you have a date that consits of 2019 2 1
The date goes backwords by a month for some reason.

`var s = d.replace(/[ :]/g, "-").split("-")
  console.log(new Date(s[0], s[1] - 1, s[2]));
`

Answer (score 6):

A solution that works for both IOS and Android, and avoid string manipulation when it isn't required is

```
let fullDate = "1991-03-29 00:00:00";
let date = new Date(fullDate);

// In case its IOS, parse the fulldate parts and re-create the date object.
if(Number.isNaN(date.getMonth())) {
  let arr = fullDate.split(/[- :]/);
  date = new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still looking for it.

works for me in IE, Safari, IOS-FF, IOS-Safari ... etc.

```
getIOSSaveDateObj = function(dateString){
    if(dateString.indexOf('-') > 0){
        var arr = dateString.split(/[- :]/);
        var date = new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
    }else{
        var arr = dateString.split(/[. :]/);
        var date = new Date(arr[2], arr[1]-1, arr[0], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: this works very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had such a hard time trying to solve this, i finally went for an easier solution and used [moment.js](https://momentjs.com). Not much you need to do just declare the dates and works in every device.

Answer (score -1):

Try with `var d = new Date("2015/12/31 00:00:00");` Works for me.

Comment: This does not work on my iPhone MN4P2X/A with Safari. It needs the T inbetween the date and the time or it returns 'Invalid Date'

Answer (score -3):

Also

```
var d = new Date("2015/12/31T00:00:00");
```

works for me :)

Thanks @dda

Comment: Doesn't work for me without replacing the space with a `T`

Comment: This does not work on my iPhone MN4P2X/A with Safari. It needs the T inbetween the date and the time or it returns 'Invalid Date'

Comment: @NULLpointer  it worked for me, maybe due to old version.
Anyway, I edited my answer to your comments.

Comment: Correction to my comment above - your editted answer (with the T replacing the space) this works for me.