# Javascript Math.Ceil not working in iOS Cordova Hybrid App

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova

very strange issue I am seeing. I have attached 2 screenshots, one of which is on Android the other is on iOS. When I test my app on emulator, I get the correct number. When I test on Android, I get the correct number. But when it's on iOS, for some reason my Math.Ceil (in javascript) returns a NaN number on iOS. Here's my function currently:

```
 var diffHours = Math.ceil((today.getTime() - creDate.getTime()) / (60 * 60 * 1000));
            if (diffHours < 1) {
                tmp[k].Difference = "Posted < 1 hours ago.";
            } else {
                tmp[k].Difference = "Posted " + diffHours + " hours ago.";
            }
```

Where diffHours returns NaN on iOS only (So I know this is not a math issue, the number I get is correct just not on iOS).

Anyone have any idea why this could be?

If not, is there an alternative I can use to Math.Ceil that I can use that will give me same result?

**UPDATE**

Here are one examples of values that's being passed in

```
today = Fri Aug 28 2015 12:25:30 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) 
creDate = Thu Aug 27 2015 00:06:54 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Attached Images (sorry the size is so big):

- Android

[image: Correct_Math_Ceil]

- iOS

[image]

Comment: Need to see entire example as value of some variable are unknown in posted code..

Comment: @RayonDabre I think this is an iOS issue, not code. As you see, same thing on Android gets correct number. As I stated, I do not believe this is a math issue for I get the correct number in plain javascript/emulator and on the actual android device. These 2 screenshots are from the same account, same page, same everything. Just on iOS I'm getting 'NaN' from a Math.Ceil function. I think this may be an issue for anyone using Math.Ceil in a Hybrid App on iOS.

Comment: Yes, iOS do have some issues with Date functions, I would suggest you to refer this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363673/javascript-date-is-invalid-on-ios or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324178/javascript-date-parsing-on-iphone

Comment: I'm not sure if that's it, I tried both with no prevail. But I did update my post with actual numbers so you can see what's being passed in.

Comment: Looks good to me...It needs some serious debugging i suppose..