# Inconsistent behavior of JavaScript Date() function in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, date

I use the `Date()` function to convert MySQL Date to the JS Date object.
Following is the code of how I was doing it:

```js
var a = "2019-03-12 12:30:03"; //MySQL Date

function MySQLToDate(dateString) {
   if (typeof dateString === 'string') {
      return new Date(dateString);
   }
   else {
      return dateString; //in case the argument is already an object
   }
}

alert(MySQLToDate(a));
//iOS Output: Invalid Date
//Normal Output: Tue Mar 12 2019 12:30:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

It was working absolutely fine as expected until I tested it in iPad browsers.

It returns `Invalid Date` in iOS. And of course, using the prototype function of `Date()` like `getDate()`, `getMonth()` etc return `Nan`.

So to overcome this situation, I researched and in one of the answers, I found out that passing the MySQL date directly into the JS Date function is a wrong practice. [[Source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13363791/7749600)

Now my code looks like following:

```js
var a = "2019-03-12 12:30:03"; //MySQL Date

function MySQLToDate(dateString) {
   if (typeof dateString === 'string') {
      return new Date(dateString.replace(" ","T"));
   } 
   else {
       return dateString; //in case the argument is already an object
   }
}

alert(MySQLToDate(a));
//iOS Output: Tue Mar 12 2019 18:00:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
//Normal Output: Tue Mar 12 2019 12:30:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

This solution is not giving an Invalid Date Error but literally gives an Invalid Date.

I also tried splitting the MySQL date and passing year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds into the `Date()` but the time in the object is still wrong.

Your answers are most welcome.

Comment: @RK_15 That's the same question to whose answer (accepted one) I've gave credit in my question. That answer will give you a wrong date time rather than an Invalid Date.

Comment: "2019-03-12 12:30:03" is not a format supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent. Apple browsers typically return an invalid date. "2019-03-12T12:30:03" should be parsed as local, but Apple browsers parse it as UTC. When manually parsing, remember to subtract 1 from the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string and then use the Date's constructor:

```
// Use this constructor
    new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

// code goes like this
    let tokens = "2019-03-12 12:30:03".split(/[-: ]/g)
    let date = new Date(tokens[0], parseInt(tokens[1]) -1, tokens[2], tokens[3], tokens[4], tokens[5]);
    console.log(date);
```

This solution is working in safari, chrome and firefox browser.

Comment: That should be `new Date(tokens[0], tokens[1] - 1, ...)` and the bits aren'r really tokens, they're substrings. ;-)

Comment: I have corrected it

Answer (score 1):

The "invalid" time you're getting looks a lot like a "double" IST timezone date. IST = India Standard Time is 5.5 hours (5 hours 30 minutes) ahead of Greenwich Mean Time (GMT+5.5).

When parsing/replacing the `'T'` in your date, make sure to add a `'Z'` on the end, to indicate Zulu time. Zulu time is timezone independent (UTC).

```
return new Date(dateString.replace(" ","T") + "Z");
```

Not sure if the iPad is choosing a timezone by itself or not, but either way you're not specifying any Timezone, so you leave it open for it's own interpretation and liking.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. Apple browsers parse ISO 8601 formatted timestamps without a timezone as UTC (which is inconsistent with ISO 8601 and ECMA-262). Adding "Z" will change the timestamp from local to UTC in all implementations.

Comment: Thanks, @RobG and @Ramon, I tried this one without adding T and Z but made a slight change which is `return new Date(dateString.replace(/-/g, '/'));`. It's working absolutely fine for multiple timezones.

Comment: @RJ—that is a terrible solution as it changes the format to one not supported by ECMA-262 meaning results are implementation dependent. It's likely to fail at some point, you just haven't discovered when yet. [*RK_15's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55176524/257182) is a much better solution as it's standards compliant.