# React js Problem with iPhone app (string and date errors)

Tags: javascript, iphone, reactjs, string, responsive-design

I have a responsive react / reactstrap app to compute and calculate user total time in using the app : clicks on "Start" when starting and I store string time in the DB "21:00:00" for example then click "Finish" and calculate now Date and call a ComputeTotal() function to calculate the timing.

When I use the app on PC (even in responsive / iPhone mode) it works , but when I deploy (on App engine) and open it with my iPhone, the string date are NaN:NaN:NaN (the ones when I use a function to compute() ) .

PC app :

[image: PC version]

iPhone version :

[image: iphone version]

The function I use to calculte the total timing  ("Horaire total du jour") :

```
CalculerTotal = () => {

  var TotalHeure = 0;
  var TotalMinutes = 0; 
  var TotalSeconds = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.events.length; i++) {
    if (this.state.events[i].arrivee !== "" &&this.state.events[i].depart !== "") {
      const d1 = new Date('1970-01-01 ' + this.state.events[i].depart);
      const d2 = new Date('1970-01-01 ' + this.state.events[i].arrivee);
      const diff = d1 - d2;
      const hours = Math.floor(diff/(1000*60*60));
      const mins = Math.floor((diff-(hours*1000*60*60)) / (1000*60));
      const secs = Math.floor((diff-(hours*1000*60*60)-(mins*1000*60)) / 1000);
      TotalHeure += hours; 
      TotalMinutes += mins;
      TotalSeconds += secs;
    }
}

if (TotalSeconds > 59) {
while (TotalSeconds >= 0) {
    if (TotalSeconds - 60 >= 0) {
      TotalSeconds = TotalSeconds - 60;
      TotalMinutes += 1;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

if (TotalMinutes > 59) {
while (TotalMinutes >= 0) {
if (TotalMinutes - 60 >= 0) {
TotalMinutes = TotalMinutes - 60;
TotalHeure += 1;
} else {
break;
}
}
}

var resHeures = (TotalHeure<10?'0':'') + TotalHeure;
var resMinutes = (TotalMinutes<10?'0':'') + TotalMinutes;
var resSecondes = (TotalSeconds<10?'0':'') + TotalSeconds;
return (`${resHeures}:${resMinutes}:${resSecondes}`)

}
```

In the iPhone I got NaN:NaN:NaN as result.

What could be the reason ?

Thanks

**EDIT 1 :**

In Android phones, it works normally.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13363673/1746830

Comment: I hope you're not storing duration as a string in the database... that's what numbers are for.

Comment: I think you should refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13363791/5081918

Comment: Yes I'm storing them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Duplicate of stackoverflow.com/q/13363673/1746830