# new Date does not give me correct value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ipad, redux-form

I get this problem with datefields ONLY on iPad. On my PC with Chrome and Edge it works perfectly fine.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me please?

on BEFORE I get **2000-01-03 00:00:00**

```
alert("BEFORE ---  "+formatedDate);  
formatedDate = new Date(formatedDate) == "Invalid Date" ? 0 : new Date(formatedDate);
alert("AFTER   ---   "+formatedDate);
```

on AFTER I get **0**

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363673/javascript-date-is-invalid-on-ios/13363791) might be useful.

Comment: @Jax-p Thaks. that solved it. You should post an answer so I can award the points to you.

Comment: Yes it did. thanks Jax-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is setting `formatedDate` in your code, it is not a properly formatted ISO date string.

If it was formatted properly, it should be `2000-01-03T00:00:00Z` (timezone depending).

Safari cannot create a date object with the date string you are providing.