# Javascript not working properly on mobile device

Tags: javascript

I'm having this script which counts up from a given date. But for some reasons it says Nah Nah Nah when i'm visiting from phone but on pc its working perfectly anyone with a clue why? :)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Month Day, Year Hour:Minute:Second, id-of-element-container
  countUpFromTime("Jan 1, 2014 12:00:00", 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
};

function countUpFromTime(countFrom, id) {
  countFrom = new Date(countFrom).getTime();
  var now = new Date(),
    countFrom = new Date(countFrom),
    timeDifference = (now - countFrom);

  var secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24,
    secondsInAHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;

  days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1);
  hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) / (secondsInAHour) * 1);
  mins = Math.floor(((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
  secs = Math.floor((((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

  var idEl = document.getElementById(id);
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('days')[0].innerHTML = days;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].innerHTML = hours;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].innerHTML = mins;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('seconds')[0].innerHTML = secs;

  clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);
  countUpFromTime.interval = setTimeout(function() {
    countUpFromTime(countFrom, id);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="countup" id="countup1">
  <span class="timeel days" style="">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefDays" style="">Days</span>
  <span class="timeel hours">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefHours">Hours &</span>
  <span class="timeel minutes">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefMinutes">Minutes &</span>
  <span class="timeel seconds">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefSeconds">Seconds</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it say "[NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)"? It might help to include the relevant HTML to make a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: is it saying `NaN NaN NaN` not sure what ins `Nah` is... NaN translate to not a number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript date is invalid on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363673/javascript-date-is-invalid-on-ios). Also see [Javascript date parsing on Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324178/) and [Invalid date in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/) and [Safari Javascript Date() NaN Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883699/), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay found out it was because i change the date string with a php variable but had to get it in the same format F, d, Y, H:i:s